# Can't find any of the new 1.9 Email options

Tags: rwd-theme

My Magento version is CE 1.9.0.1.

I want to customise the header and footer of my email templates, and the inline CSS, as explained here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_responsive_emails.html#newsletter-template

However none of the admin panel options for these customisations are there in System > Configuration > GENERAL > Design > Transactional Emails. For example I have no option for Email Header Template / Email Footer Template / Non-inline CSS files.

Also if I go to System > Transactional Emails, I cannot load the Email Header/Footer templates. Also the file app/locale/en_US/template/email/html/header.html does not exist.

I haven't found any other missing files or config options - it just seems that all of this email stuff is missing.

We have another site, also 1.9.0.1, but installed more recently, which uses the same theme, which does have these options.

Has anyone else experienced the problem?

Thanks

EDIT: After Erik Hansen's answer, I realised the other website is 1.9.1 and the website I am using is 1.9.0.1. Stupid mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the responsive emails were not released until Magento EE 1.14.1 and Magento CE 1.9.1, as you can see from the title of [that article](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_responsive_emails.html) that you linked to. So you will need to upgrade to the latest CE version in order to use the new responsive email functionality.

Comment: Oh, gosh, I didn't realise I'd misread it. Thank you for correcting me.